# Accessing External IP from LAN through an access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nginx

I am hosting a webserver on a relatively older computer with Nginx as its reverse proxy. I used portforwarding to forward the 80 and 443 port of the server and I set that up in the DNS records of a domain registerar. I am currently using an apex domain.

When I try to access my website(external IP) while connected with the modem, it works great. So I suppose that Hairpinning is enabled by default in the modem. I have a router as well which is WDS Bridged to the main modem.

When I'm connected to the router however, my site does not work.
I can't say that the router is not connected to internet though because all the other websites work properly while connected to the router.

Also, if I use an internal ip (192.168.x.x) that also works fine when I was using SSH to configure my webserver. DHCP is disabled in the router, so I am not sure why I can't access my website through the router.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access my website through the router"? Where exactly (speaking from a network standpoint) is the client located?

Comment: My webserver is connected to the router. When I am connected to the modem, I am able to access the website but when I connect to the router, I am not able to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this is, in fact a hairpinning issue, not with the modem, but with the router. The issue was simple, I just had to add the internal server so that would be I had to add

```
    192.168.1.x domain.com
```

to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for laptop I was accessing the site from and I had to edit `/etc/hosts/` file on the linux server.
This fixed the issue, but I still have to do this on every device that I connect to the router with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a problem with your DNS records or settings somewhere, which is quite common when hosting sites in multiple networks (i.e. internally and externally).

Perform nslookups on your site while connected to each network (modem, router, externally). Externally you should see your public IP, internally you should see the private IP of the server (192.168.x.x). If you're seeing a public IP while connected internally, that network isn't configured to use your internal DNS.

If, however, the situation is that you can access your site via the public IP internally while connected to the modem, but not while you're connected to the router, my guess is that the router is configured as a wireless AP, rather than a bridge. I.E. it's NATting packets sent from ethernet across the wireless bridge, rather than just switching them. In this case you'll have to adjust the settings on your router. Make a backup before changing anything, and download the manual **before** you lose internet.

Comment: I am using a TP Link Archer C50 router. In its quick settings, I had the option to choose between using it as a router or an access point. I chose router and then I configured WDS for 5ghz band. How do I disable NAT in it cuz I agree that double NAT could be a problem in this case

Comment: Quick update, I suppose that the router is works without NAT altogether. Because that specific model's firmware doesn't allow me to configure NAT. I could try flashing OpenWRT but im afraid I might end up bricking the router...

Comment: What is your modem model?

Comment: It's a Nokia G2425G-A prolly flashed with a custom firmware by the ISP